# Multiple child processes writing to parent the result of a unix command executed with popen

Tags: c, unix, pipe, fork, popen

I have to write a C code that:

- accepts 'n' command line arguments (unix commands)
- for each arguments the main program launches two child processes
- each child process will execute the unix command (args[i]) with a random delay and using popen and then will send the answer to the parent process
  the parent process will print only the first n/2 responses received
- only a pipe channel must be used for the communication between the parent process and the child processes

I have written the following source code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <wait.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>

    #define DIM 100

    int main(int argc, char *args)
    {
       int t, nrR=argc-1,f,p[2],prID,d;
       FILE *fd1, *fd2;

       //PIPE channel creation
       if(pipe(p)<0)
       {
          perror("PIPE channel creation error!");
          exit(1);
       }
       for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
       {
          d=strlen(args[i]);

          if((f=fork())==0)
          {  //FIRST CHILD PROCESS

             char *buffer = malloc(DIM*sizeof(char));
             //The child process will only write to the parent process
             close(p[0]);
             //Delay the process execution
             srand(time(NULL));
             int s=rand()%2;
             sleep(s);
             fd1 = popen(args[i],"r");

             //Writing the PID to the parent process
             prID=getpid();
             if(write(p[1],&prID,sizeof(int))!=sizeof(int))
             {
                perror("PIPE writing error!");
                exit(3);
             }

             //Writing the command string length
             if(write(p[1],&d,sizeof(int))!=sizeof(int))
             {
                perror("PIPE writing error!");
                exit(3);
             }

             //Writing the command string
             if(write(p[1],args[i],sizeof(args[i]))!=sizeof(args[i]))
             {
                perror("PIPE writing error!");
                exit(3);
             }

             //Writing the command output result string
             while(fread(buffer,DIM,1,fd1)>0)
             {
                if(write(p[1],buffer,sizeof(buffer))!=sizeof(buffer))
                {
                    perror("PIPE writing error!");
                    exit(3);
                }
             }
             free(buffer);  
             pclose(fd1);
             exit(i+1);
          }
          else if((f=fork())==0)
          {  //SECOND CHILD PROCESS
             char *buffer = malloc(DIM*sizeof(char));
             //The child process will only write to the parent process
             close(p[0]);
             //Delay the process execution
             srand(time(NULL));
             int s=rand()%2;
             sleep(s);
             fd2 = popen(args[i],"r");

             //Writing the PID to the parent process
             prID=getpid();
             if(write(p[1],&prID,sizeof(int))!=sizeof(int))
             {
                perror("PIPE writing error!");
                exit(3);
             }

             //Writing the command string length
             if(write(p[1],&d,sizeof(int))!=sizeof(int))
             {
                perror("PIPE writing error!");
                exit(3);
             }

             //Writing the command string
             if(write(p[1],args[i],sizeof(args[i]))!=sizeof(args[i]))
             {
                perror("PIPE writing error!");
                exit(3);
             }

             //Writing the command output result string
             while(fread(buffer,DIM,1,fd2)>0)
             {
                if(write(p[1],buffer,sizeof(buffer))!=sizeof(buffer))
                {
                    perror("PIPE writing error!");
                    exit(3);
                }
             }
             free(buffer);  
             pclose(fd2);
             exit(i+2);
          } 
       }
       if(f>0)
       {
          //Parent process behavior
          close(p[1]); //The parent process will not write to the child processes
          for(i=0;i<nrR;i++)
          {
             //we will read and print only the first 'n' responses received through the pipe channel from the child processes
             waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
             char *cmd,*buffer;

             //Read the pid of the child process
             if(read(p[0],&prID,sizeof(int))!=sizeof(int))
             {
                perror("PIPE reading error!")
                exit(2);
             }
             //Read the command string length
             if(read(p[0],&d,sizeof(int))!=sizeof(int))
             {
                perror("PIPE reading error!")
                exit(2);
             }
             //Read the command
             cmd = malloc(d*sizeof(char));
             if(read(p[0],cmd,sizeof(cmd))!=sizeof(cmd))
             {
                perror("PIPE reading error!")
                exit(2);
             }
             printf("\nProcess %d -> %s:\n",prID,cmd);
             //Read and print the unix command result
             buffer = malloc(DIM*sizeof(char));
             while(read(p[0],buffer,sizeof(buffer))>0)
             {
                printf("%s",buffer);
             }
             free(buffer);
             free(cmd);

             //Wait for other n/2 child processes to terminate
             while(waitpid(-1,NULL,0)>0)
             {
                if(errno == ECHILD)
                   break;
             }
          }
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

My code compiles and runs; I have tried "ls" as argument. The program does not show the expected output. I have introduced some check prints and I detected the following issues:

- In the child processes I cannot read the whole "ls" output from the fd1 and fd2
- The parent process does not receive anything/does not receive correctly the "ls" output string sent through the pipe from the child processes (It receives though correctly the child process ID and the command name).

Could there be problems caused by the multiples child processes which try to write (probably in the same time) in the same PIPE channel? Or are there some other issues that I didn't think of?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Each child needs it's own pipes back to parent, so p should be a 2d array, p[child][file id].
At no time are you trying to collect the command data at no point are you accessing the pipe relating to stdout of the command. How do you plan to send the commands output  back to the parent. You need to tell the parent how many bytes of text coming, then writing it all is probably the best solution. It allows you to malloc a buffer ready to store it as a string and it can also be block read rather than a byte at a time til a '\0'

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
I have to underline that the described task must be done using a single pipe channel in the code.

And yes, you're right, I should have determined the dimension of all the message received through popen and send it in one piece to the parent. 

Thanks again. :)